# Jaeger add custom tag when storing the traces in the backend

Tags: jaeger

We have two Jaeger collectors deployed on two datacenters (A and B), these Jaeger collectors share the same Cassandra cluster as the backend.

Is there any way to add a custom tag like `region=A` or `region=B` to the traces in the Collector instances so that when I'm querying in the Jaeger UI, I can see where the trace is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--collector.tags` option for that.

```
$ docker run --rm jaegertracing/jaeger-collector:1.52.0 help | grep collector.tags
      --collector.tags string                                     One or more tags to be added to the Process tags of all spans passing through this collector. Ex: key1=value1,key2=${envVar:defaultValue}
```